# Why is the Parse push notification error occurring?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to enable push notifications, but for some reason I am getting this error. The notification gets sent to parse, but not to the user.

[image]

Comment: I take it this is your phone and you have the app installed and notifications turned on for it?  This isn't a simulator right?

Comment: I am using my phone. I am actually using test flight with multiple users if that is relevant.

Comment: I have a feeling this is wrong http://puu.sh/lZzU8/48ed4422ce.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently Apple changed how APNS Certificates work - you'll notice that newly created push certificates have the name "Apple Push Services:" and not "Apple Production IOS Push Services:". Apparently [production certificates can be used for Sandbox and Production now](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action): "Establish connectivity between your notification server, the Apple Push Notification service sandbox, and production environments to deliver remote notifications to your app."

I'm not sure how much they need to change on the backend side on Parse's end, but I noticed adding to AWS SNS didn't work for me last time I tried.

Comment: So I'm not getting the above error anymore, but now I am getting a very ambiguous error. http://puu.sh/lZSg9/1c6135866a.png

Comment: Did you try recently? Because in the past week they likely have fixed it, at least, Amazon SNS fixed it so it works again.

Comment: @stackerleet It works and you changed nothing? Same here.